# Prove that $f$ on $[a,b]$ has only a finite number of zeros.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Assume that there exists no $x\in[a,b]$ such  that $f(x)=0=f'(x).$ Prove that the set {$t\in[a,b]:f(t)=0$} of zeros of $f$ is finite.

What I have done is, let the set contain infinite number of points. Then by the Bolzano Weierstrass theorem there exists a sequence $<x_n>$ which has a convergent subsequence $<{x_n}_k>$ convergent to $c$. Then $f(c)=0$. But I got stuck in proving $f'(c)=0$.

Comment: What have you tried? What if you assume not, can you work towards a contradiction?

Comment: @Michael: Got it and therefore deleted the comment.

Comment: Looks like you are almost done...Bolzano-Weierstrass is a good idea here.

Comment: How have you tried proving $f'(c)=0$?

Comment: @Michael that is where i got stuck

Comment: Well, Paramanand gives an answer below.  You could also try applying the definition of $f'(c)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh it is wrong to say f will be strictly monotonic at c if f'(c) is not zero there

Comment: @Eklavya: Do you know the meaning of strictly monotone *at a point*? This is different from monotonicity in an interval. $f$ is said to be strictly increasing at a point $c$ if there is a neighborhood $I$ of $c$ such that if $x \in I, x < c$ then $f(x) < f(c)$ and if $x \in I, x > c$ then $f(x) > f(c)$. This is *very different from* saying that $f$ is strictly increasing in some neighborhood of $c$. See "Monotonicity at a point" in my blog post http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/07/monotone-functions-part-1.html

Comment: @Eklavya: If $f'(c) > 0$ then $f$ is strictly increasing at point $c$ in the sense of the definition given in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition that we're on a closed, bounded interval hints that we could take advantage of its [compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space). Indeed:

- Let $N$ be the points on which $f$ is nonzero $$N=\{t \,|\, t\in[a,b], f(t)\neq 0\}$$ As $f$ is continuous, $N$ is open on $[a,b]$.
- Let $z_i$ be all zero points of $f$ and let $Z_i$ be open neighborhoods of them on [a,b] such that $z_i$ is the only zero point of $f$ in $Z_i$: $$\forall x\in Z_i\setminus \{z_i\}:\, f(x)\neq 0$$ Such neighborhoods exists because $f'(z_i)\neq 0$, so sufficiently close to $z_i$ function $f(x)$ behaves like $f'(z_i) (x - z_i)$.
- Obviously $N\cup \bigcup_i Z_i=[a,b]$ so the sets form an open cover of $[a,b]$.
- By the definition of a compact space, there exists a finite subcover. However, since each $z_i$ is contained only in $Z_i$ and nowhere else, every such subcover must include all $Z_i$. Therefore the number of $Z_i$ is finite.

Comment: @Pudlak excellent idea

Answer (score 9):

Let's suppose that the set $A = \{t\mid t \in [a, b],\, f(t) = 0\}$ is infinite and since it is bounded there is a point $c \in [a, b]$ such that $c$ is a limit point of $A$. Clearly by continuity $f(c) = 0$ and hence $c \in A$.

Now it is obvious that $f'(c) = 0$ otherwise $f$ will be strictly monotone at $c$ and there will be a neighborhood of $c$ where $f$ does not vanish except at $c$. And this will contradict that $c$ is a limit point of $A$. Thus we have $f(c) = f'(c) = 0$. Contradiction!!!

Comment: Or  we can note that if $c_n$ converges to $c$ with $c$ not equal to any $c_n$ and $f(c_n)=f(c)=0$ then $(f(c)-f(c_n))/(c-c_n) $ converges to $f'(c)$...So $f'(c))=0.$

Answer (score 4):

Hint

If $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=L$ and $(x_n)\to c$ then $\lim\left(\frac{f(x_n)-f(c)}{x_n-c}\right)=L$.